# Xamarin SignaturePadView GetImage Android Black Background

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I always get a black background color, even when I set it to white:

```
  SignaturePadView sigView = new SignaturePadView(Forms.Context);
  sigView.StrokeColor = Color.Black;
  sigView.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
  var stream = await sigView.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It is working on iOS, but Android doesn't. Is there something else I can do to get a white background?

EDIT:
The resulting jpg-file has a black background, not the view!

Comment: Can I see the whole of say MainActivity? It works for me when I run official sample: https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad/blob/master/samples/Sample.Android/MainActivity.cs

Comment: It is inside a DependencyService of a Xamarin.Forms App. The Service creates a Dialog with LinearLayout which includes the SignaturePadView

Comment: The example does not save the image to a file. But thats what i need to do. The jpg-file is all black, the view is displayed correctly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try using GetImage method of the Signature pad View ?

> sigView.GetImage(Android.Graphics.Color.Black,
>   Android.Graphics.Color.White, false);

We uses this and gets in white background with black signature.

Answer (score 2):

Saving transparent layer in jpg results in black background. Save in png instead to keep the alpha layer.